# Python web scraping not working using BeautifulSoup and Request

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Currently learning Python so apologies for the stupid question but for some reason I can't seem to extract the £13.50 value from the following website:

"https://www.asos.com/the-north-face/the-north-face-norm-cotton-cap-in-black/prd/204512287?clr=black&colourWayId=204512317&cid=50056"

The below is the code I tried but it returns none:

```
import requests
import bs4

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36"
}

url = "https://www.asos.com/the-north-face/the-north-face-norm-cotton-cap-in-black/prd/204512287?clr=black&colourWayId=204512317&cid=50056"

page = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")

current_price = soup.find('div', class_='a0j7k')
print(current_price)
```

I can see the tag exists when I inspect the website:

[html tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM9JQ.png)

I can also grab one of the above tags no problem but the price always returns none.

Please can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The price data you see is inside `<script>` element, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. To parse it use `re`/`json`:

```py
import json
import re

import requests

url = "https://www.asos.com/the-north-face/the-north-face-norm-cotton-cap-in-black/prd/204512287?clr=black&colourWayId=204512317&cid=50056"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0"
}

html_text = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
data = re.search(r"stockPriceResponse = '(.*?)';", html_text).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

# uncomment this to print all data
# print(data)

price = data[0]["productPrice"]["current"]["text"]
print(price)
```

Prints:

```
£13.50
```

---

The `data` contains:

```py
[
    {
        "productId": 204512287,
        "productPrice": {
            "current": {
                "value": 13.5,
                "text": "£13.50",
                "versionId": "PRMP000002000200000008090911220231009020000",
                "conversionId": "0",
            },
            "previous": {
                "value": 24,
                "text": "£24.00",
                "versionId": "PRMP000002000200000008090911220231009020000",
                "conversionId": "0",
            },
            "rrp": {
                "value": None,
                "text": None,
                "versionId": "PRMP000002000200000008090911220231009020000",
                "conversionId": "0",
            },
            "xrp": {
                "value": 13.5,
                "text": "£13.50",
                "versionId": "PRMP000002000200000008090911220231009020000",
                "conversionId": "0",
            },
            "currency": "GBP",
            "isMarkedDown": True,
            "isOutletPrice": False,
            "startDateTime": "2023-10-09T01:00:00Z",
            "previousEndDate": "2023-09-30T23:00:00Z",
            "lowestPriceInLast30DaysValue": 9,
            "lowestPriceInLast30DaysText": "£9.00",
            "lowestPriceInLast30DaysEndDate": "2023-10-06T07:00:59Z",
            "lowestPriceInLast30DaysPercentage": -50,
            "discountPercentage": 43,
        },
        "hasMultipleColoursInStock": False,
        "hasMultiplePricesInStock": False,
        "isInStock": True,
        "variants": [
            {
                "id": 204512325,
                "isInStock": True,
                "isLowInStock": False,
                "stockLastUpdatedDate": "2023-06-02T13:24:15.661Z",
                "warehouse": None,
                "source": None,
                "seller": None,
                "price": {
                    "current": {
                        "value": 13.5,
                        "text": "£13.50",
                        "versionId": "PRMP000002000200000008090911220231009020000",
                        "conversionId": "0",
                    },
                    "previous": {
                        "value": 24,
                        "text": "£24.00",
                        "versionId": "PRMP000002000200000008090911220231009020000",
                        "conversionId": "0",
                    },
                    "rrp": {
                        "value": None,
                        "text": None,
                        "versionId": "PRMP000002000200000008090911220231009020000",
                        "conversionId": "0",
                    },
                    "xrp": {
                        "value": 13.5,
                        "text": "£13.50",
                        "versionId": "PRMP000002000200000008090911220231009020000",
                        "conversionId": "0",
                    },
                    "currency": "GBP",
                    "isMarkedDown": True,
                    "isOutletPrice": False,
                    "startDateTime": "2023-10-09T01:00:00Z",
                    "previousEndDate": "2023-09-30T23:00:00Z",
                    "lowestPriceInLast30DaysValue": 9,
                    "lowestPriceInLast30DaysText": "£9.00",
                    "lowestPriceInLast30DaysEndDate": "2023-10-06T07:00:59Z",
                    "lowestPriceInLast30DaysPercentage": -50,
                    "discountPercentage": 43,
                },
            }
        ],
    }
]
```